# Displaying a table based on drop down value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display a table of questions based on what the user selected on the drop down menu. Once the user selects a category, I want to send that data to the api using get method. I'm using angularjs as the controller. The problem is that the table is not being populated by any values after calling the get method. I am not sure if my approach is correct.

html

```
<h3>View Quiz By:</h3>

    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
        <option value="math">Math</option>
        <option value="science">Science</option>
        <option value="history">History</option>
        <option value="compscience">Computer Science</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <tt>singleSelect = {{data.singleSelect}}</tt>

    <br><br><br>



    <div ng-controller="selectOptionController">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Question</th>
                <th>Answer</th>
                <th>OptionA</th>
                <th>OptionB</th>
                <th>OptionC</th>
                <th>OptionD</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in result">
                <td>{{row.id}}</td>
                <td>{{row.question}}</td>
                <td>{{row.answer}}</td>
                <td>{{row.optionA}}</td>
                <td>{{row.optionB}}</td>
                <td>{{row.optionC}}</td>
                <td>{{row.optionD}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

angularjs

```
angular.module('staticSelect', [])
.controller('selectOptionController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
            singleSelect: null
    };

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/quiz/webapi/quiz/"+data)
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.result = response.data;
    });

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once the user selects a category, I want to send that data to the api using get method.

You can add `ng-change` to your `<select>`

```
<select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-change="onChange()">
    <option value="math">Math</option>
    <option value="science">Science</option>
    <option value="history">History</option>
    <option value="compscience">Computer Science</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

and in Controller write:

```
$scope.onChange = function(){
  $http.get("http://localhost:8080/quiz/webapi/quiz/"+$scope.data.singleSelect)
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.result = response.data;
});
};
```

---

A a side note:

If you want to build `select` options by angularjs way use `ng-options`:

```
$scope.list = [
    {value: 'science', name: 'Science'},
    {value: 'history', name: 'History'},
    {value: 'compscience', name: 'Computer Science'},
    {value: 'other', name: 'Other'}
  ];
```

and your select:

```
<select name="singleSelect" 
        ng-model="data.singleSelect" 
        ng-change="onChange(data.singleSelect)"
        ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in list"
> </select>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eOtsaAEEPqH8fcgOc4G9?p=preview)